# String can not have zero length

Tags: vb.net

Get that error when trying to use the function when compiled.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf(""))
    Dim DllFileName As String = FileName.Replace("", "")
    DllListBox.Items.Add(DllFileName)
End Sub
```

Figured out it got something to do with this line :

```
Dim DllFileName As String = FileName.Replace("", "").
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Well, what would that actually mean? Replace nothing with nothing? Replacing *something* with nothing would make more sense here.

Comment: Imagine replacing `""` with `"a"` - what would be the result?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here?:

```
FileName.Replace("", "")
```

The first string argument is the string to search for in `FileName`.  The second is the string to replace it with.  You're trying to replace nothing with nothing.  The result of such an operation, if it were allowed, would be the same as no operation at all:

```
Dim DllFileName As String = FileName
```

As the error states, the first argument can't be an empty string.  The system can't meaningfully search for an empty string inside of a non-empty string.